# p:dialog shows empty values when when I go to the next page of the p:datatable using paginator

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have been using onEdit  in the p:datatable and it works fine.My data table has a pagintor and  shows 5 records per page.so when I click on the onEdit in the first page event.getObject gets the changed value in the bean.Now when I go the next page the event.getObject does not work and returns the old value only.

Same with the dialog box.In the table I have a link when clicked opens a dialog box in whcih I am populating few fields with the values from the row selected.It works fine in the first page and When I navigate to other pages gives empty values.

Here is my jsf code:

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{mybean.userList}"
                             var="item"
                             id="dataTab"
                             widgetVar="usersTable"
                             tableStyleClass="data"  paginator="true" rows="5"  
                             filteredValue="#{userController.filteredUsers}"
                             editable="true"
                             rowKey="#{item}"
                             >
                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit"   listener="#{mybean.onEdit}" update=":userForm:growl" />  
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{mybean.onCancel}" update=":userForm:growl" /> 
                    <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputPanel>  
                         <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                         <p:inputText id="globalFilter"     onkeyup="('usersTable').filter()"   style="width:150px" />  
                    </p:outputPanel>     
                    </f:facet>


                    <p:column sortBy="#{item.firstName}" filterBy="#{item.firstName}" 
                              filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                         <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="First Name" />  
                        </f:facet>
                             <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText  value="#{item.firstName}" />
                             </f:facet>
                             <f:facet name="input">  
            <p:inputText value="#{item.firstName}" style="width:100%"/>  
        </f:facet>  
                          </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  sortBy="#{item.lastName}" filterBy="#{item.lastName}" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                        <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="Last Name" />  
                        </f:facet>

                    <p:column headerText="Update" style="width:6%">  
                     <p:rowEditor />  
                    </p:column>    




                                        </p:dataTable>


<p:dialog id="modalDialog"
                                          header="Delete User?"
                                          modal="true"
                                          resizable="false"
                                          draggable="false"
                                          widgetVar="delUserConf"
                                          >  

                   <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" style="width: 150px;">
                                        <h:outputLabel value="Firat Name"  style="font-weight: bold"/>

                                        <h:outputText value="Last Name"  style="border: none"/>

                                    </h:panelGrid>

                                </p:dialog>
```

Here is the code in my bean for the edit functionality:

```
public String onEdit(RowEditEvent event)
    {
User user=(User)event.getObject());
      user.getFirstName();
}
```

I did not add the link that I have in my form which pops up the dialog.Also I read that this might be because of Lazy loading and I am not sure about it.I am populating my table with a list and not the model.

Could you let me know what should I do to make it work?

Comment: what kind of manegedbeand these your using

Comment: Using a view scoped bean

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should switch to SessionBean scope because the scope view is released when there are changes in the view. Try SessionBean. Also you can call from view scope any sessionbean like this, where controladorMB is a sessionbean

```
 public void detallesPersona() {
    try {
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ValueExpression vex = ctx.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(ctx.getELContext(), "#{controladorMB}", ControladorMB.class);
        ControladorMB gMB = (ControladorMB) vex.getValue(ctx.getELContext());
        this.setSelectedPersona(gMB.getPersonaBean().detallesPersonas(this.selectedPersona.getIdPersona()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it because a SessionScoped bean is used? Is there any alternative if we are using ViewScoped bean.

Comment: Managed beans registered in 
viewscope remain available 
as long as the user stays on 
the same view. Navigating away 
from that view will cause beans 
registered in that view’s scope 
to be deallocated. If you want to keep data please use application or session scope